# IoBuildAsynchronousFsdRequest with IRP_MJ_WRITE

Tags: c++, wdm, filter-driver

I developed a WDM filter driver on disk driver. I want to send an asynchronous request to write data on disk. The windows will crash when I delete the `writeBuffer` memory in `WriteDataIRPCompletion` function.

My question is: How can I safely free the `writeBuffer` memory without crashing?

This my send request code:

```
#pragma PAGEDCODE
NTSTATUS WriteToDeviceRoutine() {
    PMYDRIVER_WRITE_CONTEXT context = (PMYDRIVER_WRITE_CONTEXT)ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool,sizeof(PMYDRIVER_WRITE_CONTEXT));
    context->writeBuffer = new(NonPagedPool) unsigned char[4096];

    PIRP pNewIrp = IoBuildAsynchronousFsdRequest(IRP_MJ_WRITE,
         pdx->LowerDeviceObject,
         context->writeBuffer,(wroteRecordNodeCount<<SHIFT_BIT),
         &startingOffset,NULL);
   IoSetCompletionRoutine(pNewIrp,WriteDataIRPCompletion,context,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE);
   IoCallDriver(pdx->LowerDeviceObject,pNewIrp);
}
```

This is my completion routine code:

```
#pragma LOCKEDCODE
NTSTATUS WriteDataIRPCompletion(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,IN PIRP driverIrp,IN PVOID Context) {
   PMDL mdl,nextMdl;
   KdPrint((" WriteDataIRPCompletion \n"));
   PMYDRIVER_WRITE_CONTEXT writeContext = (PMYDRIVER_WRITE_CONTEXT) Context;
   if(driverIrp->MdlAddress!=NULL){
      for(mdl=driverIrp->MdlAddress;mdl!=NULL;mdl = nextMdl) {
         nextMdl = mdl->Next;
         MmUnlockPages(mdl);
         IoFreeMdl(mdl);
         KdPrint(("mdl clear\n"));
     }
     driverIrp->MdlAddress = NULL;
   }
   delete [] writeContext->writeBuffer;
   if(Context)
      ExFreePool(Context);

    KdPrint(("leave WriteDataIRPCompletion \n"));
    return STATUS_CONTINUE_COMPLETION;
}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with what you're dealing with, but isn't the `ExFreePool(Context)` call trying to delete an invalidated buffer now? You got the `writeBuffer` from `Context`, which you seem to be deleting/freeing twice.

Comment: I tried,but system didn't free the memory. I checked it from windows task manager tool,the kernel non-Paged memory not to be released.

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544590(v=vs.85).aspx), it looks like you should be allocating the memory using [`ExAllocatePool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544501(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of using the `new` operator. The `ExFreePool` function is meant to deallocate memory allocated with that function, which you don't seem to be using. Did you check that?

Comment: Please see updated post, specifically the part of you not setting your `delete`d memory to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I removed  "delete [] writeContext->writeBuffer;" and allocated writeBuffer through "ExAllocatePool" function ,system still cannot free memory. I still try to find another way to safely free write buffer memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you error in next line

```
context = ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool,sizeof(PMYDRIVER_WRITE_CONTEXT));
```

when must be

```
context = ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool,sizeof(MYDRIVER_WRITE_CONTEXT));
```

not `sizeof(PMYDRIVER_WRITE_CONTEXT)` but `sizeof(MYDRIVER_WRITE_CONTEXT)` you allocate not structure but pointer to it.

this not produce error only if your `MYDRIVER_WRITE_CONTEXT` containing single field `writeBuffer` and no more data. otherwise you overwrite allocated memory (which is only sizeof(PVOID)) and this create bug

and about completion for [`IoBuildAsynchronousFsdRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548310(v=vs.85).aspx). unfortunately documentation not very good. here sated that

> Before calling IoFreeIrp, an additional step is required to free the
>   buffer for an IRP built by IoBuildAsynchronousFsdRequest if the
>   following are all true:
>
> ```
> The buffer was allocated from system memory pool.
> ```

but then all attention for

> The Irp->MdlAddress field is non-NULL.

however we must check and for `IRP_DEALLOCATE_BUFFER|IRP_BUFFERED_IO`, without this we can leak `Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer`. need next code

```
if (Irp->Flags & IRP_BUFFERED_IO)
{
    if (Irp->Flags & IRP_INPUT_OPERATION)
    {
        if (!NT_ERROR(Irp->IoStatus.Status) && Irp->IoStatus.Information)
        {
            memcpy( Irp->UserBuffer, Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer, Irp->IoStatus.Information );
        }
    }

    if (Irp->Flags & IRP_DEALLOCATE_BUFFER)
    {
        ExFreePool(Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer);
        Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer = 0;
    }

    Irp->Flags &= ~(IRP_DEALLOCATE_BUFFER|IRP_BUFFERED_IO);
}
```

---

and check for `if (writeContext)` **after** use `writeContext->writeBuffer` already senseless and nosense. really you need do check for `context != NULL` yet in `WriteToDeviceRoutine()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the specifics of what you're working with, so here're a few details that caught my attention.

### In `WriteDataIRPCompletion` function

> ```
> PMYDRIVER_WRITE_CONTEXT writeContext = (PMYDRIVER_WRITE_CONTEXT) Context;
> // ...
> delete [] writeContext->writeBuffer;
> if(Context)
>      ExFreePool(Context);
> ```

Notice that your `writeContext` originates from your `Context` argument. However, you seem to be deleting/freeing the allocated memory twice.

The `ExFreePool` function [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544590(v=vs.85).aspx) state:

> Specifies the address of the block of pool memory being deallocated.

It looks like the `delete [] writeContext->writeBuffer;` line might be causing the problem and it just needs to be removed.

As it is right now, part of the memory that should be `free`d by the function has already been manually `delete`d by the time you invoke `ExFreePool`, ***but not set to `NULL`***, which in turn causes `ExFreePool` to receive a now-invalid pointer (i.e. a non-null pointer pointing to de-allocated memory) in its `Context` argument, causing the crash.

### In `WriteToDeviceRoutine` function

The documentation for `ExFreePool` explicitly states that it deallocates memory that has been allocated with other functions, such as `ExAllocatePool` and other friends.

However, your code is trying to allocate/deallocate the `writeContext->writeBuffer` directly using the `new`/`delete` operators respectively. It seems like you should be allocating your memory with `ExAllocatePool` and then deallocating with `ExFreePool` instead of trying to do things manually like that.

These functions may be organizing the memory in a specific way and if/when this pre-condition is not met in `ExFreePool`, it could end up in a crash.

---

On a separate note, it seems odd that you check `if(Context)` is null before invoking `ExFreePool`, but not above before you try to type-cast for your local `writeContext` variable and use it.

Maybe you should also check at that first point of use? If `Context` is *always* non-null, then the check might also be unnecessary prior to invoking `ExFreePool`.

Comment: your comment is very reasonable,but the system still cannot free memory. I still try to find another way to safely free write buffer memory.

Comment: @JoeHsu What Windows version are you using?

Comment: @JoeHsu How do you know that the non-paged number reported by the manager should do down immediately? Can you point to docs that support that assumption?

Comment: Because when I used [IoBuildSynchronousFsdRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548330(v=vs.85).aspx) function to send request,I can delete the write buffer memory after request finish, and windows manager show non-paged memory usage down immediately.Since, I think that windows manager can show non-paged memory usage immediately.

Comment: @JoeHsu Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see where the docs say anything about paged/non-paged memory pools. It does mention that "IRPs that are created by **IoBuildSynchronousFsdRequest** must be completed by a driver's call to **IoCompleteRequest**." and that it "must not call **IoFreeIrp**, because the I/O manager frees these synchronous IRPs after IoCompleteRequest has been called." (emphasis original), but at least the code posted doesn't seem to be calling them. How is this function related to the code you posted, which isn't using it?

Comment: @JoeHsu BTW, your question title is about IoBuild**A**synchronousFsdRequest, not IoBuild**S**ynchronousFsdRequest, which is what you referenced in your comment. Maybe you're using the wrong function?

Comment: here no  twice same memory deletion - `writeContext` and `writeContext->writeBuffer` different buffers, so code is formally correct. yes - check for `if (writeContext)` **after** use `writeContext->writeBuffer` already senseless and nosense